# ¿Cómo puedo poner una advertencia cuando no haya internet en una app del tipo webview?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola quisiera saber si puedo agregar algún código o advertencia que me permita saber que no dispongo de conexión a internet en una aplicación del tipo webview. Por ejemplo que salga "No dispones de internet en este momento para conectar con la aplicación"

Este es mi código
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mivisor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hp.fpvfinanzaspersonales">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.hp.fpvfinanzaspersonales;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mivisor);
       web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
       WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
       settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       web.loadUrl(url);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: podrias servirte esto: https://blogs.tunelko.com/2011/12/26/android-sdk-como-detecto-la-conexion-a-internet/

Answer (score 2):

Si requieres saber si hay internet disponible, debes revisar si existe conectividad con [**isAvailable()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isAvailable()) y si existe conectividad y es posible establecer conexión con [**isConnected()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected()), mediante este método

```
private static ConnectivityManager manager;

public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Muy importante agregar los permisos en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, para determinar el estatus de la red:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

y para tener conectividad:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

En base a lo anterior puedes validar antes de cargar la url en el `WebView`, si no existe puedes mostrar un Toast, Snackbar o lo que desees para indicarle al usuario que no existe conexión a internet:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mivisor);
       web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
       WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
       settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

       if(isOnline(getApplicationContext()){ //Carga url
         web.loadUrl(url);
       }else{ //No existe conexión.
           Toast.makeText(this, "No existe contexión a internet, intente más tarde!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

}
```

Comment: Me genera errores de compilación error: cannot find symbol method isOnline(Context)

Comment: @ManuAbella debes agregar el método que indico al inicio de la respuesta, así como los permisos en tu AndroidManifest.xml